# Vulkan dynamic UBO weird numbers

Tags: rendering, vulkan

[image]

Why these numbers??
I have created a dynamic ubo and two objects, one for view and proj and the other for model.

Here I update the objects:

```
Render::UniformBufferObject ubo{};
        Render::UniformBufferObject2 ubo2{};
        

        ubo2.model = &model_transform.GetWorldMatrix();
        
        ubo.view =  &EditorCamera_transform.GetWorldMatrix().Inverse();
          
        ubo.proj = &current_camera->GetProjectionMatrix();

        // map memory without a staging buffer
        void* data;
        auto memory = uniform_buffer->get_ubo_memory();
        Render::VulkanMemoryAllocator::get_instance()->map_buffer_allocation(memory[current_image], &data);
        memcpy(data, &ubo, sizeof(ubo));
        memcpy(data, &ubo2, sizeof(ubo2));
        Render::VulkanMemoryAllocator::get_instance()->unmap_buffer_allocation(memory[current_image]);
```

Here binding and draw command:

```
std::array<uint32_t, 2> dynamicOffsets =
            { i * static_cast<uint32_t>(Render::StandardUniformBuffer::required_alignment(sizeof(Maths::Matrix4)*2)),
              i* static_cast<uint32_t>(Render::StandardUniformBuffer::required_alignment(sizeof(Maths::Matrix4)))
            };

            cmd.bindDescriptorSets(
                vk::PipelineBindPoint::eGraphics,
                *pipeline->get_pipeline_layout(),
                0,
                2,
                descriptor_set->get_descriptor_sets()->data(),
                2,
                dynamicOffsets.data());

            cmd.drawIndexed(static_cast<uint32_t>(index_buffer->get_primative_indices_size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually hard to say anything for sure without knowing a lot more about your code base,
but do `Render::UniformBufferObject` and `Render::UniformBufferObject2` consist of pointers to matrices, and not actual matrices (unless the `&` operator is overloaded somehow) ?

You're not supposed to write pointers to values into UBOs and expect the GPU to dereference them.

You also seem to be overwriting the content you wrote from `ubo` with contents in `ubo2` ; `data` points to the same location in both of the `memcpy` calls.

Assuming `Render::UniformBufferObject` and `Render::UniformBufferObject2` actually consists of matrix value members:

```
struct Render::UniformBufferObject {
  glm::mat4 view, proj
};
struct Render::UniformBufferObject2 {
  glm::mat4 model
};
```

Here's how I'd write the values to the uniform buffer, assuming `Render::StandardUniformBuffer::required_alignment` works the way I expect it to:

```
// Assuming uniform_buffer has enough size taking UBO offset alignment into account.
void* data;
auto memory = uniform_buffer->get_ubo_memory();
Render::VulkanMemoryAllocator::get_instance()->map_buffer_allocation(memory[current_image], &data);

// Write to the location we'll be telling vkCmdBindDescriptorSets in the form of dynamic offsets.
auto& ubo = reinterpret_cast<Render::UniformBufferObject*>(static_cast<uint8_t*>(data) + 0);
auto& ubo2 = reinterpret_cast<Render::UniformBufferObject2*>(static_cast<uint8_t*>(data) + Render::StandardUniformBuffer::required_alignment(sizeof(Render::UniformBufferObject)));

ubo.view = EditorCamera_transform.GetWorldMatrix().Inverse();
ubo.proj = current_camera->GetProjectionMatrix();
ubo2.model = model_transform.GetWorldMatrix();

// Remember to call vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges if the backing memory is NOT host coherent.

Render::VulkanMemoryAllocator::get_instance()->unmap_buffer_allocation(memory[current_image]);
```

And the dynamic offsets for `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets`:

```
// Offsets where we wrote the values:
std::array<uint32_t, 2> dynamicOffsets = {
  0,
  Render::StandardUniformBuffer::required_alignment(sizeof(Render::UniformBufferObject))
};
```